# match one line break, but not two

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to match all line breaks that are not followed by another line break so that I can convert the first line break to a space, but still keep paragraphs separated, so that:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 


ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 


cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
```

will be transformed to this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 


ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 


cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
```

So far I have `.*?\r\n(?<!(\r\n))`, which I feel is really close, but I cannot seem to get it quite right. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the regex `\r?\n(?!\r?\n)`. You can find an online explanation and demonstration [here](https://regex101.com/r/qZ5zV1/1).

This regex uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that the line break is followed by another line break. The line breaks are matched by `\r?\n` to conform to the standard, because some line breaks are represented by a carriage return (`\r`) followed by a newline (`\n`), while others are *just* a newline.

Comment: great answer. I was just confused on syntax. this is really straightforward, thank you so much.

Comment: @sln Please explain how this is wrong. thomas, the author of the question appears to disagree with you.

Comment: I posted an answer that explains it all.

Comment: i'm agree with @sln

Comment: Yes this is not the real answer

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as it will match the **2nd** of 2 line breaks also (because it is NOT followed by a line break), which is unwanted. Here is the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33170447/3161220

Answer (score 4):

The only real way to find a solitary line break is to find it between two non whitespace chars.
Any other way and it turns out it might be bordered by any number of linebreak's.
So, you can't just look one way and not the other, and either way you look could be
padded with non-breaking whitespace, so you're better off doing it this way.

The simplest is to do a global
Find: `(\S[^\S\r\n]*)\r\n([^\S\r\n]*\S)`
Replace: `$1 $2` (<-that's 'capture group 1' + 'space' + 'capture group 2')

```
 ( \S [^\S\r\n]* )             # (1)
 \r \n 
 ( [^\S\r\n]* \S )             # (2)
```

**Extra info**

Also, the capture groups can be replaced with look around's
as well as trim spurious non-linebreak whitespace.

Find:  `(?<=\S)[^\S\r\n]*\r\n[^\S\r\n]*(?=\S)`
Replace:  (<- that's a space)

```
 (?<= \S )
 [^\S\r\n]* \r \n [^\S\r\n]* 
 (?= \S )
```

Comment: Thanks @sln, but `(\S[^\S\r\n]*)\r\n([^\S\r\n]*\S)` seems to match the last letter of a line, the line break, and first letter of the next line.

Comment: @thomas - `(\S[^\S\r\n]*)\r\n([^\S\r\n]*\S) seems to match the last letter of a line , the line break, and first letter of the next line` Yep, that's right _and_ is the correct way to do it. What does the replacement do?