# How do I remove single line breaks?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove single line breaks in my text but not double ones.

I'm able to replace lines using `\r\n`. How can I remove single line breaks?

**EDIT:** I also need to add space before each line. For example if original text is:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

it must be converted to:

```
line1 line2 line3
```

Comment: What do you do with triple line breaks?

Comment: the selected text probably won't have triple line breaks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I've got your point - you need to convert single `\r\n` to space but leave double, triple and so on.

You can use replace function of Notepad++ and this regular expression

```
(?<!\r\n)\r\n(?!\r\n)
```

Here we have negative lookbehind of `\r\n`, then `\r\n` itself and then negative lookahead of `\r\n`, so it matches single occurence of `\r\n` having no predecessors and no successors of the same characters.

Something like:
[image]

Note: you have to check "Regular expression" radiobutton at the bottom of form. Also field "replace with" should contain single space character.

As a result it converts following text:

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
```

into this one:

```
line1 line2 line3

line4 line5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: Not quite the same result OP wants, I suppose. Since "Join lines" in Notepad++ actually converts **each** `\r\n` into space character - doesn't matter if it was simgle or double one.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev:- Hmm..I see that. I think I misunderstood the question.